# What Unit is the MP4 "chpl" Box's Timestamp in?

Tags: video, video-processing

**Note:** While I'm asking about the "chpl" box, I assume the same question could be asked about the "krok" and "dlay" boxes with the same answer.

I'm trying to get the chapter information from an MP4 file. I use the library [mp4parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) to read the boxes, but sadly it doesn't know about chapters, so I'm parsing this data myself using the [spec](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/flv/video_file_format_spec_v10.pdf).

Since the spec states each chapter contains of a timestamp UI64, a title size UI8 and a title UI8[titleSize], this is my code to read the chapters:

```java
ByteBuffer buffer = // 

int chapterCount = buffer.get();
List<Chapter> chapters = new ArrayList<>(chapterCount);

for (int i = 0; i < chapterCount; i++) {
    final long timestamp = buffer.getLong();
    final int titleSize = buffer.get();

    final byte[] bytes = new byte[titleSize];
    buffer.get(bytes);
    final String title = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    chapters.add(new Chapter(title).startTime(timestamp));
}
```

This works; all chapter titles are parsed correctly, so I assume the timestamps are correct, too.

However now I have timestamps that I can't map to a time, e.g.:

```
0           -> 0:00
70070000    -> ~0:21
13605925667 -> ~22:22
```

There is no obvious relationship between the values and the time they correspond to.

After trying to guess the factor without any luck, I read the spec and found the "TimeScale" in the "mvhd" box. It's 1000, so the timestamps in the "chpl" box should have the unit "ms". Obviously they don't.

How do I figure out / calculate which unit the "chpl" timestamp's value is in?

Comment: Please share your file which makes debugging this a lot easier.

Comment: @MarkusSchumann It's going to be hard to find a MP4 file that is neither copyrighted nor a home movie and has chapters, but I'll try to find something.

Comment: You could truncate the 'mdat' in file and then is probably fair use.

Comment: @MarkusSchumann I tried adding chapters to [this file](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4) using ffmpeg; then the chapters are as expected. So since my video players are able to read the chapters of the video in the question just fine they must be saved in another format or version. I'm still new to all this and I have no idea how to truncate anything yet =/

Comment: I'd open your file in a hex editor, search for 'mdat' and delete everthing past 'mdat'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an official documentation for this but all the files I checked seemed to have absolut timestamps with a timebase of `1/10000000` (10^-7 seconds or 0.1μs).

For your values this would mean

```
0           -> 00:00
70070000    -> 00:07
13605925667 -> 22:40
```

Perhaps the chapter data in the `chpl` atom of your file is "old" and differs from the data in the separate chapter track (which encodes them the "QuickTime-way" with the `chap` atom) which is why whatever program you're using gives you `0:21` and `22:22` instead.